# Projectively splitting module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, terminology, modules

Is there a name for such class of modules $M$ such that $M\rightarrow N\rightarrow 0$ splits for every $N$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the [semisimple modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module). ("Semisimple" is usually defined by the condition that every injection into M splits, but that's clearly equivalent to your condition.)